# "Application access denied." when viewing roles

Tags: personalization, user-management, role-management

I am getting an `Application access denied.` message when viewing the roles, when trying to edit a personization rule ("where the current user is a member of the specific role").

When I click `specific` to bring up the window to choose the role(s), I get an `Application access denied`. error message.

This works when logged in as an admin, but not an editor.

I am guessing, I need to assign a specific role, or set access somewhere, but I'm unsure where.

Edit:

Should add, this is in Sitecore 9

I am personalizing one of the controls on the page (same error if done view Content Editor or Experience Editor).

This is done as an editor (A user with the roles sitecore\Designer, sitecore\Author.. I later tried adding sitecore\Analytics Content Profiling and sitecore\Analytics Personalization but this didn't fix issue)

Step 1: Go to final layout edit screen, and choose control I want to personize..
[image]

Step 2: Default Personization screen
[image]

Step 3: Add a new `Rule` choosing `where the current user is a member of the specific role`
[image]

Step 4: When I click `Specific` to bring up screen to choose roles, I get below error
[image]

If I try the above as an admin, I get the expected screen without error:

[image]

Comment: I am not sure i fully understand your question , but it looks a security issue, please check https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/82/setting_up_and_maintaining/security_and_administration/users_roles_and_domains/the_security_roles

Comment: Plus info for Naim's comment. Try out the following built in roles: Sitecore Client Account Managing OR Sitecore Client Authoring. These are giving access to the User Manager features if I got it correctly.

Comment: Some screen captures and more details may help understanding the exact scenario.

Comment: I've added some screen captures above

Comment: Tamás Tárnok suggestion of adding Sitecore Client Account Managing OR Sitecore Client Authoring roles lets window appear, but gives this user access to user management, which I do not want..

Comment: Did you ever get the right answer you were looking for. I got the same situation (sitecore 8.2 though) and indeed, the role Sitecore Client Account Managing does provide access to the user roles for Personalization but also gives that user access to the User and Role Management tools, which is not desirable. Any update would be great!

Answer (score 0):

I tried the suggestion of adding `Sitecore Client Account Managing` OR `Sitecore Client Authoring` roles but these were problematic in the following ways:

- Adding **Sitecore Client Account Managing** resolved the issue but gave
  our editors have access to too many user management functions
- Adding **Sitecore Client Authoring** didn't resolve the issue

What resolved the issue for me was doing the following:

1. Navigate to the following item in the Core database

   ```
     /sitecore/content/Applications/Security/Edit User
   ```
2. Click on Access Viewer under Security
3. Use the Security Editor to give Read permissions to the role
   which needs to see the '`Select Roles`' page

(Resolved in Sitecore 8.2 Update 7)